# Highcharts with Custom Background in Cross Platform app development

Tags: javascript, android, highcharts

I have a strange Problem with [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) display :( 
I am using Highcharts in Cross Platform app development. I am using a custom background for highchart. It is working very well in iOS but not appearing in Android. Though chart is there but not visible. When I remove the background it is working well. 
Following is my Code:

```
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {

      className: 'skies',
      plotBackgroundImage: 'appImages/graph_color_background3.jpg',

    },
```

Any Idea about this ?

Comment: did you try backgroundColor: 'transparent' and then put a background-image to the container??

Comment: tried this but no success.

Comment: did you try the image in png format also

Comment: i think android already have problems with png format :( And it is not working as well.

Comment: oh ok, I don't know that. Thanks for the info

Comment: So if you are trying to set container background image, and this doesn't work, for me it means that paths are incorrect. Or try to set `backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'`